# Valgrind Qt Application on Mac OSX - reporting incompatible processor

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, valgrind

I'm not really experienced in using the compile chain via terminal on Unix or Mac OSX, so I just assume I made a huge mistake during that, but who knows.

I'm trying to use Valgrind with the Qt Creator on Mac OSX 10.7.5 on a Mid 2012 MacBook Pro. I'm using Qt 5.0.1 and the most recent valgrind version. I compiled valgrind using this guide: http://prateekvjoshi.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/how-to-install-valgrind-on-mac-os-x/ and had to add `#define __private_extern__ extern` to a few files to make it work. Google told me that.

After compiling (and checking if it worked), I tried using valgrind in Qt Creator and via the terminal as well. Funny enough, the analyzing crashes (both times) and I get the following:

```
Incompatible processor. This Qt build requires the following features:
sse3 ssse3
Aborted. Incompatible processor: missing feature 0x18 - sse3.
** Process crashed **
** Analyzing finished **
```

This makes roundabout 0 sense to me. I'm developing with the Qt Creator since quite a while and compiling just works perfect. I tried using gcc instead of clang as compiler to no avail. Neither google nor the stackoverflow search did help me regarding that.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: might be due to http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/cmpxchg8b.htm - its been a requirement for valgrind since... well forever and some linux systems ( as your mac osx thingy is ) dont forward cpu flags correctly. So you may be able to comment out the tests for (machine_get_hwcaps) and it still runs fine. But that is only a shot in the dark ( http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/quot-fatal-error-unsupported-CPU-quot-on-Via-C7-Esther-processor-td42491.html )

Comment: @Najzero Didn't help me solve the problem, but helped me to identify how it's not an issue with valgrind itself it seems. After doing the self diagnostics of valgrind without having the problem, I tried to use valgrind on a very simple compiled c++ file (basically just an int main() { return 1;} ), which worked flawless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my build of valgrind itself seems to have bugged out. After trying to recompile it numerous times, I was able to get it to work with installing it through macports.

Eh well. Better than nothing.